# what is the correct way to add data array to the array state as well

Tags: reactjs

I want to add array data to my state array, then how should I do it
my array props

```
0 : {name : "David", Age : 32},
1 : {name : "John", Age : 23}
```

my state

```
data : [
 {name : "Joy", Age : 24},
 {name : "Dave", Age : 28}
]
```

my Code

```
this.setState({
            data : [...this.sate.data, props]
         })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat` like this:

```
this.setState({
            data : [...this.state.data].concat(props)
         })
```

Edit: consider using `prevState` as other answers mentioned:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  data : [...prevState.data].concat(props)
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work, when you fix the spelling error, but you may want to use prevState in case of batch updates.

```
// Sample data:
const props = [
 {name: "David", Age: 32},
 {name: "John", Age: 23}
];
```

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  data: [...prevState.data, ...props]
}));
```

I'm guessing `props` is also an array, so you need to apply `...` spread operator here too.

Comment: not the wrong props, just I'm not clear about how to shorten my coding
i have try use this `this.setState((prevState) => ({
  data : [...prevState.data].concat(props)
}))` thank you for your answer, maybe it will be useful for me next time

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, the correct way to add element to your state array is:

```
(supposed that your state array is called arrayVar)
this.setState(prevState => ({
  arrayvar: [...prevState.arrayVar, ...data]
}))
```